# What is MAX allowed cost in php password_hash?

Tags: php, encryption, bcrypt

What is the MAX allowed **cost** for PHP **password_hash()** function?

```
    $options = [
      'cost' => 18,
    ];
    $res = password_hash("donkey", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
    var_dump($res);
```

I tried with these **costs** so far and the time is quickly climbing.

- 15 took about 1.623... seconds
- 18 took about 12.756... seconds
- 19 took about 25.149... seconds
- 20 took about 51.215... seconds

I tried with 120 and got:

> Invalid bcrypt cost parameter specified

So I know there is a limit, but I'm not seeing it in PHP docs.
Anyone know what it is?

Comment: Do you see a pattern? I predict at 21 it will take about 102 seconds, ... and at 30 it will take about 14.5 hours.

Comment: Yeah, it beat me.. I gave up after almost two hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [wikipedia article about the bcrypt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) shows that 31 is the maximum value for `cost`.